# Texture painting. Why not mark all seams and unwrap later?

Tags: uv, texture-painting

This is a rather general question. I started figuring out how Texture Painting works, the second time now to be honest. I don´t understand why to bother and mark certain seams, when you can just mark all edges at once  and unwrap them afterwards. It worked last time, when I was just using an existing texture without trying to paint. So what would be wrong about marking all edges as seams?

Comment: "*So what would be wrong about marking all edges as seams?*" You'll get a very fragmented UV layout where every single face is an island. The more discontinuities you have the larger the risk of issues, artifacts, uneven density, visible border seams etc.

Comment: Because there will be as many seams in the texture as there are edges in the mesh. Seams are often sometihing to be hidden due to multiple reasons like possible visible seam in texture, problems with mipmap (artifacts while zooming out) etc. Not to mention that handling with such UV map (and hence images mapped to it) can be a nightmare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a more simple approach to getting started with Texture Paint, then consider using 'Smart Unwrap' from the Unwrap menu - no need to mark any seams with this option, and you can get on to painting. If you decide you really need a better map, then you can create a second UV map with the correctly marked seams and then bring in the paint from the previous mapping to a new image with the Clone Tool using the second correct mapping.